# My UIButtons (using auto layout) seem not be drawn correctly when changing orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibutton

When I started this viewController, I had in mind the following layout, drawn in the Interface Builder with an auto layout:
[image]

Then I thought, why not adding a calculator mode that would switch the buttons `500`, `100`, `50` and `10` to `/`, `x`, `-` and `+` with a flip transition.

So as the layout was already defined, I thought I could take the existing buttons (the ones I want to flip), make them as the containers of my transitions and create programmatically the buttons `500`, `100`, `50`, `10`, `/`, `x`, `-` and `+` based on the frame of those containers (in order to avoid to manage the auto layout programmatically.

So I wrote the following code in my viewController (all views are UIButton):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    initLayout()        
}

func initLayout() {
    container500.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    container100.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    container50.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    container10.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    button500 = createCalculatorButton(NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(500, numberStyle: .NoStyle)+"wwwww",
        frame: container500.bounds, color: container500.backgroundColor!, action: "fiveHundreds:")
    button100 = createCalculatorButton(NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(100, numberStyle: .NoStyle)+"xxxxx",
        frame: container100.bounds, color: container100.backgroundColor!, action: "oneHundred:")
    button50 = createCalculatorButton(NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(50, numberStyle: .NoStyle)+"yyyyy", frame: container50.bounds, color: container50.backgroundColor!, action: "fifty:")
    button10 = createCalculatorButton(NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(10, numberStyle: .NoStyle)+"zzzzz", frame: container10.bounds, color: container10.backgroundColor!, action: "ten:")

    buttonDivision = createCalculatorButton("/", frame: container500.bounds, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), action: "div:")
    buttonMultiplication = createCalculatorButton("x", frame: container100.bounds, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), action: "mult:")
    buttonSubtraction = createCalculatorButton("-", frame: container50.bounds, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), action: "sub:")
    buttonAddition = createCalculatorButton("+", frame: container10.bounds, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), action: "add:")

    container500.addSubview(button500)
    container100.addSubview(button100)
    container50.addSubview(button50)
    container10.addSubview(button10)
}

func createCalculatorButton(title: String, frame: CGRect, color: UIColor, action: Selector) -> UIButton {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = color
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1

    button.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    button.addTarget(self, action: action, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return button
}

@IBAction func calculatorMod(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.flipTransition(view1: self.button500, view2: self.buttonDivision)
        GraphicHelper.delay(0.1) {
            self.flipTransition(view1: self.button100, view2: self.buttonMultiplication)
        }
        GraphicHelper.delay(0.2) {
            self.flipTransition(view1: self.button50, view2: self.buttonSubtraction)
        }
        GraphicHelper.delay(0.3) {
            self.flipTransition(view1: self.button10, view2: self.buttonAddition)
        }
    }

func flipTransition(#view1: UIView, view2: UIView) {
    var transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions!
    let duration = 0.5

    var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

    if view1.superview != nil {
        views = (frontView: view1, backView: view2)
        transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft
    }
    else {
        views = (frontView: view2, backView: view1)
        transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight
    }
    UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView, toView: views.backView, duration: duration, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)
}
```

And here is the result:
When entering in portrait. OK:

[image]

And then switching to landscape. NOT OK:

[image]

When entering in portrait and then switching to calculator mode. OK:

[image]

When entering in landscape. OK:

[image]

And then switching to portrait. NOT OK:

[image]

And then switching to Calculator mode. NOT OK:

[image]

By seeing this, I can guess the UIButtons before changing the phone's orientation are still there (or they seem to be) but I don't understand where is the problem in my code.

I even tried

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    button500.removeFromSuperview()
    button100.removeFromSuperview()
    button50.removeFromSuperview()
    button10.removeFromSuperview()

    buttonDivision.removeFromSuperview()
    buttonMultiplication.removeFromSuperview()
    buttonSubtraction.removeFromSuperview()
    buttonAddition.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea where my problem is?

UPDATE:

Here is the view hierarchy when changing from portrait to landscape:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please share your project link...

Comment: I don't have any link. I put all the methods that interact with the layout (except the action ones at it's not really relevant here)